# Как удалить несколько символов из вывода переменной

Tags: python

Подскажите, как удалить лишние символы.

```
#содержимое второго по счету тега <i></i> - это год издания
    Book_year = OurCell.find_all('i')[1]
```

Выводит 2002-02-01. Как изменить ее, чтобы остался только год 2002?

Comment: `OurCell.find_all('i')[1].split('-')[0]` ?

Comment: OurCell.find_all('i')[1][:4] @MaxU Зачем делить, если нужны только первые символы, а формат стабилен?

Comment: @Lecron, если год состоит __гарантированно__ из 4 цифр, то ваш вариант более эффективен....

Comment: Оба варианта не работают :( Полный скрипт здесь https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=300820.msg2355898#msg2355898 python lookisbn.py --url="http://www.lookupbyisbn.com/Search/Book/9780521681001/1/"
Short Answer Questions in Anaesthesia Simon Bricker 2002-02-01 .pdf

Comment: python lookisbn.py --url="http://www.lookupbyisbn.com/Search/Book/9780521681001/1/"
Вывод:
Short Answer Questions in Anaesthesia Simon Bricker 2002-02-01 .pdf
Нужно чтобы было:
Short Answer Questions in Anaesthesia Simon Bricker 2002.pdf

Comment: Естественно, раз возвращается не строка, к которой идет преобразование только после получения. Вот после этого преобразования, берите срез `[:4]` или разбивайте `.split('-')[0]`

Comment: Book_year = OurCell.find_all('i')[1]
    Year = Book_year[:4]
    print Book_name.string, Book_author.string, Year.string,".pdf" Не работает :(

Comment: После преобразования к строке, а не до! by_str = Book_year.string; year = by_str[:4]

Comment: Получилось! Только после года лишний пробел остается.

Answer (score 0):

Можно преобразовать текст в дату и взять год.

```
from datetime import datetime

date_str = '2002-02-01'
date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
print(date.year)
```

Comment: Можно, но в данном случае менее эффективно.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а творить махинации со срезами строк всегда оптимальное решение? Мне всегда казалось, что от этого нужно уходить в сторону регулярных выражений и др.